# What is the PAD size required for the Battery negative and Positive pads voltage (min 30v to max 42v) current (min 500 mA to max 15 A)?

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, pcb-design, circuit-design, eaglecad

I am creating a circuit for low voltage battery management systems (10s 1p 36v 2.5A battery pack). All the circuits is perfectly done from schematics to Layout.

But i have small doubt in  Battery negative and positive, Charge negative and load negative Pads. for this in schematics i have used a testpoint so that i can modify based on the power constraints.

**The battery and load negative will be connected to the board and the Current (min 500 mA - 15A max)and voltage (30v to 42v)  Will pass from B- (Battery negative) to P- (Load negative) on the board during discharge process.**

**How much Length and width of the Pad size should i give for B- based on the Power (30 v to 42v ) (500 mA to 15A)**

[image]

[image]

Comment: How are you going to use and install this? You may want the ability to connect and disconnect for maintenance without soldering : in which case, use screw terminals or suitable connectors.

Comment: its Just a Prototype project that i am doing i would like to solder ithe battery negative wire and load wire in the board thats my requirement .so based on the Power constraints how to size the Pad. kindly help me.